# NN Keras Regression: Different Input for Training and Prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression, prediction

I want to achieve a sports `prediction` where the (test) input for a model is only 1 (ID) out of 20 variables (that training gets)

I build a NN Regression model in python with keras that uses ~ 20 input variables, including `ID, minutes_played, score,...`.
Now I am wondering if it possible to feed the trained model (with 20 vars) only the `ID` variable and get a `"prediction"` for that ID.

Or how else can I predict something with no useful input data?

Answer (score 1):

> how else can I predict something with no useful input data?

You can't! The whole point of traning a model with input data, is to make predictions for similar data points.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How else than nn regression can I achieve this?Suggestions?

Comment: Machine learning algorithms use data to learn patterns and make predictions. If you don't have sufficient data it is very hard to make accurate predictions. If you post more information about your problem maybe somebody will be able to help.